# How to avoid a line break (wrap) between two inline elements

Tags: html, css

I want to use a large number of checkboxes with labels, therefore they won't be displayed below each other, but float like ordinary text. What I have tried so far is this:

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/><label for='one'>one</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='two' id='two' value='two'/><label for='two'>two</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='three' id='three' value='three'/><label for='three'>three</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='four' id='four' value='four'/><label for='four'>four</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='five' id='five' value='five'/><label for='five'>five</label>
```

The actual number of checkboxes and labels is much higher, three or four lines long, depending on the size of the browser window.

Unfortunately, depending on the size of the browser window, a line wrap between the `input` (checkbox) and the `label` element may appear, although there is no space between them. This doesn't look nice, because the square box and the following text belong together and should not be on separate lines.

I tried to pack both of them in a `span` element, even with all kinds of attributes and even CSS, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Try assigning min-width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the input inside the label and consider `white-space:nowrap`.

<sup>I am using the same ID/name to make a fast copy past and to simply demonstrate the trick</sup>

```css
label {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
|| 
<label for='one'><input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/> one</label>
||
```

Comment: I had tried the same, but put the CSS into a style attribute of the label element, but that did not work. Don't understand what makes a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't super elegant, but does it do the trick for you?

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='one' id='one' value='one'/>&nbsp<label for='one'>one</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='two' id='two' value='two'/>&nbsp<label for='two'>two</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='three' id='three' value='three'/>&nbsp<label for='three'>three</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='four' id='four' value='four'/>&nbsp<label for='four'>four</label>
|| <input type='checkbox' name='five' id='five' value='five'/>&nbsp<label for='five'>five</label>
```

Comment: No, nbsp only replaces ordinary spaces with a non-breaking one. Since there was no space between the elements, there is nothing that could be replaced.